How does this IR detector work?
I am trying to get the Parallax Infrared Sensor kit (#28019) to work, but I fail to understand how it could work at all. This is the kits schematic:

And according to the documentation, you send out a 38500Hz out to the LED for 1ms, and after that you read the same pin to check for detection.
How is this possible? I would think you read the same signal you send to it, or the result of the sensor delays a bit or something?

That's crude, but could work.

I would think you read the same signal you send to it, or the result
of the sensor delays a bit or something?

Yes, there is a short delay before the sensor detects the 39 kHz optical pulses from the LED. Shortly after the pulsating optical signal is sensed, optical detector output pin is pulled to logic low. Similarly, when pulsing ceases, output pin delays a short time before returning to logic high.
At the same time, you're driving the LED with 39 kHz pulses by setting the microcontroller's GPIO pin to output. Doing so invites a bus-fight between GPIO output and optical sensor output (one can try to pull to logic high while the other tries to pull to logic low). Bus fighting should be avoided (!) and so I have suggested that this method is crude.
One would want to switch the GPIO output pin to become an input pin immediately after transmitting 39 kHz pulses to the LED. Then read the optical sensor's logical state. One would wish to drive the LED pulses for a short time to minimize bus fighting. Parallax software suggests 39 pulse train (lasting one millisecond).
It would be better to use two microcontroller GPIO pins - one to drive current to the infrared LED, and the other GPIO to read the state of sensor logical output.

The schematic fails to convey the information what parts are used and how they work.
The manual for the kit says it uses a standard 40 kHz IR receiver module, like basically those you find in TVs etc.
So it detects 40 kHz modulated light, and when it detects it, the module pulls the pin low. Therefore the pin will be low, after transmitting a burst of 40 kHz modulated light.
